# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected Exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, jscript

I am getting below exception in runtime, could anybody suggest what is wrong?

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

Exception is coming in very first line:

```
aspxAddHoverItems('tabMaster',[[['dxtcTabHover_Glass'],[''],['T0','T1','T2','T3'],['','T'],[[''],[''],[''],['']],['Img']],[['dxtcActiveTabHover_Glass'],[''],['AT0','AT1','AT2','AT3'],['','T'],[[''],[''],[''],['']],['Img']]]);

var dxo = new ASPxClientTabControl('tabMaster');
window['tabMaster'] = dxo;
dxo.uniqueID = 'ctl00$tabMaster';
dxo.RegisterServerEventAssigned(['TabClick']);
dxo.emptyHeight = true;
dxo.emptyWidth = true;
dxo.tabCount=4;
dxo.InlineInitialize();
```

Comment: Which line does it fail?

Comment: first line aspxAddHoverItems(....

Comment: Have you declared `aspxAddHoverItems` anywhere?

Comment: aspxAddHoverItems is an undefined (or unfound) function

Comment: actually i have not written this script anywhere, this script is generated in calibration.aspx[dynamic] my page: calibration.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aspxAddHoverItems` is simply unrecognized as the error suggests.  Be sure to include all necessary references and assemblies in your project.

This may be just what you need: [How to: Manually Register DevExpress Extensions to Start Using Them in an MVC Web Application](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163)

Some additional reading: [Google Search: aspxAddHoverItems is not defined](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=aspxAddHoverItems#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=aspxAddHoverItems%20is%20not%20defined&oq=aspxAddHoverItems%20is%20not%20defined&aq=f&aqi=g-mK1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i5i30.3394.4734.0.4774.15.10.0.2.2.0.172.885.6j3.9.0...0.0.oDABEIMe8PE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b1b82b70972cdaaf&biw=1581&bih=1352)